# problem with my C# code in inserting in mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, t-sql

kindly let me know how to insert two variables. its not a problem giving directly my userid and mobile in the code like

```
string insert =@"Insert into userHistory(userid,mobile) values(x,y)";
```

This is my code, but it fails to insert *(editors note: OP provided no error)*

```
int userid = 123456;
long mobile = 91888888888;
sqlConn = new MySqlConnection(/* conn string removed */);
sqlConn.Open();
string insert = 
@"Insert into userHistory(userid,mobile) values(@userid,@mobile);";

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(insert,sqlConn);    
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;    
cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@userid", userid));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@mobile", mobile));
```

Comment: "i'm not able to do it" doesn't really describe the problem. See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Hey @Pranay Rana, I think your `?`-key is stuck ;-)

Comment: Maybe it is worth trying cmd.execute() ?

Comment: cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure intead of this its cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

Comment: Wow, kind of incomprehensible question + multiple edits = understandable question. Crowd... asking? ;)

Comment: CommandType.StoredProcedure will result in calling stored procedure with name that was specified in 'insert', so this will end up with even more spectacular error

Comment: I tried with cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text . but values are not inserted in the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without more Information, I guess the type of your command should be "Text" and not CommandType.StoredProcedure, since you do not execute a SP. And you  have to execute the command (maybe this is only missing in your code)

Comment: i have tried with cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; its not inserting in my table

Comment: Did you execute the command? I don't know the exact API, but something like cmd.execute() or cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() should do it. DO you get any errors?

Answer (score 1):

this is wrong `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure` the command is should be `CommandType.Text`

You can read more about the [CommandType enumeration here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandtype.aspx).

There are some more .net [examples for MySql here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand.html)

Comment: i have tried with cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; its not inserting in my table.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;`

You are trying to execute an ad-hoc query, *not a Stored Procedure*.  Try changing it to

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```

Comment: i have tried with cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; its not inserting in my table.